# What is the cost of protecting a trademark globally?

Tags: logo, trademark

I know this is not specifically a graphic design question, but I am curious to know about the differences between protecting an image-mark (trademark as a logotype) from nation to nation.

Is there a difference between black & white versus color marks?

Is there a service that will register it in individual countries or is there an international consortium that suffices?

Do you have any tips for best-practice in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this calculator](http://www.wipo.int/madrid/en/fees/calculator.jsp?Lang=E&ForDate=20180120&Origin=US&Classes=1&ServCd=EN) About 20 000$ in either black and white or color. Mind you its just the registration before that you need to check you are actually unique.